# Generate the statistics of a table after truncating it and then repopulate it?

Tags: oracle, statistics, transparent-data-encryption

Is it necessary to generate the statistics of a table after truncating it and then repopulate it?
I have a table with several million rows in Oracle.Every week new data is recharged, truncating the table and then loading the data.

Each time a new data load is made, I must generate the statistics again. Should I also rebuild the indexes?
Some columns are encrypted with TDE.
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

As a general guidelines, it is usually recommended to do a gather stats on table whenever more than 10% of the rows are modified. So in your case, you will need to do a stats gather post data load. 
The index stats gather are taken care of if we do table stats gather using cascade option.

Comment: "If you have gathered table stats using cascade option, then index rebuilds are not required that frequently and can we done once a month or so." That sound weird. Why should he rebuild indexes every month? And nobody rebuilds an index to get a statistic for this index. There is a [related question from this user](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/222931/reindex-or-rebuild-the-indexes-of-a-table-after-truncating-it-and-then-repopulat)

Comment: My bad, removed the rebuild part.